# Appwrite and / or Spring Boot Backend

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, appwrite

I am developing mobile Apps in Flutter. Right now I was using Spring Boot for backend services like User Authentication, Data Storage and so on.
But now I had a look to appwrite as a backend abstraction layer. I can use User Authentication from there and get rid of writing my own User Authentication for every new project I do.

Are there any experiences if that is suitable? Can I use Appwrite for creating all backend services? The frontend contains no business logic, it only calls Spring Boot REST services for that. With appwrite I can use functions to do that?

Is that a good idea? Are there any compares between appwrite and Spring Boot Backends showing the advantages / disadvantages?